# How to edit css files of SweetAlert 2

Tags: css, typescript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Hello I am using sweetalert 2 to show some alerts to a project.

It supposed to look like this
[image]

but it does like this
[image]

And it because of this style. The style is set to auto. When i uncheck the css value on Inspect/Styles the swal works fine.

```
body.swal2-height-auto {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

I tried to edit this line on the plugins css file sweetalert2.css to set the height to 100%

```
body.swal2-height-auto {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

or add a showClass on ts function

```
const steps = ['1', '2', '3']
        const swalQueueStep = Swal.mixin({
          customClass: {
            container: 'container--modifier',
          },
          confirmButtonText: 'Forward',
          cancelButtonText: 'Back',
          progressSteps: steps,
          input: 'text',
          reverseButtons: true,
          validationMessage: 'This field is required'
        })
```

global.scss

```
.container--modifier{
    height:100%!important
  }
```

i saved the file but changes are not commited. Any help?